# Jenkins pipeline shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

I am using Jenkins pipeline. I have 2 queries regarding shared library 
 1. can shared library always checkout latest tag/code ?
 2. Can shared library call the main method by default ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Can shared library always checkout latest tag/code?
   By default, shared libraries checkout the code from branch which is specified at the time of configuration (In Manage Jenkins -> Configure System).
   However, if you want to checkout from a particular branch or tag, you can specify it in your Jenkinsfile as follows:
   **@Library(['sharedlib@testbranch')_**

2.Can shared library call the main method by default?
You can define the default method to be called under **call()** function in your shared file, and when you call that file from a Jenkins stage, it would be executed.
For e.g if you have a shared library file deploy.groovy, you can define the default function and other functions as follows :
[Shared library file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBx1B.png)
[image]

You can execute the default method by adding step "deploy()" in your Jenkins file and you can call the other function by adding step "deploy.someOtherFunction()" in your pipeline.

Hope this answers your question!